# Allow only certain characters in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I'm quite new to javascript so I'm looking for some help.

Is there a way to check if a string has unallowed characters? If so how? I want to return a `Boolean` if the name contains any other like Chinese and special characters like `$@#*%÷=+_€¥£₩`.

Comment: Even these `$@#*%÷=+_€¥£₩` are `UTF-8` characters. Do you mean English language alphabets only?

Comment: Umm, more like the hungarian, but even the english is good.

Answer (score 1):

You want to learn about regular expressions.

Basically, if you only allow the latin alphabet and digits, lowercase and uppercase, you can use this:

```
if (stringToTest.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/)) { ... }
```

Some documentation can be found [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml) for example.

Comment: Yes, kinda like that. However, i don't know if that supports the Hungarian Characters.

Comment: Of course it does, see what others have done: http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_cset

Comment: Hmm. The code you gave me worked almost. Actually im running a server, and when most of the players join its fine. However, a player called: HanyagElegancia couldn't join. What could be the problem?